# Architectural design for consuming big volume of data from different data sources

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, architecture

The current product implementation is: In the back end we are using spring- boot and for the front-end we have React\Redux app.

Up until now, we were working with only one database (Oracle) with a small amount of data.  Lately due to business needs (more info on the client-side) we needed to pull more data form few more databases (can be Oracle and MySql) that contain a huge amount of data.

Doing this with regular SQL via spring boot will not work due to the amount of data. We cannot work in the database since they belong to external customers and we also need to combine data for analyzing.

To summaries – I am looking for some middleware product that can work with different data-sources, able to handle the high volume of data, capabilities to create API in order to process data that coming from different sources and finally this need to be very fast in order to view the output on the client-side (Rest\React).

Will be happy to hear your stories\experience and recommendation.

Thank you

Comment: I guess what all issues you are talking about is related to `big data`. There a many open source software and technologies that can help you. I would simply suggest you `Talend` which is a data integration tool with big data tools included. I think a big data expert could help with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution could be using multiple [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html) source connector to pull data from different data sources. They(connectors) will put data into Kafka topics. [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/intro.html) is a very fast reliable streaming platform.

If you app has some requirement to process the data before serving it to front end, then you could write an application to do that and expose required endpoints to expose the data.

If you need access to raw data then Kafka ecosystem has [REST proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/index.html) which exposes topics data over REST.

So in short your pipeline looks like

Datasource(s) -> Kafka Connect -> Kafka -> Kafka REST Proxy / Custom Data processing App -> React front end.

Comment: Thank you this looks like a good direction. What about Apache Spark? Do you have some background with this product also?

Comment: What are the benefits of using Confluent implementation vs Kafka as is?

Answer (score 0):

We have recently implemented somewhat similar ask from our client. Solution is fully on AWS Cloud Native and Serverless. The back end (both data consolidation from disparate sources and Data retrieval to React) can be done in several different ways.

Data Consolidation back end - Existing Java code can be factored into Lambda Java Functions and by enabling VPC, these can also talk to On-Prem sources of Data. Alternately, Batch can be used Or Databricks if a commercial tool is ready.

Data Retrieval for React - Serverless Java functions if needed to leverage existing code/logic.

Data Storage - Redshift? Depending on your budgets.